# Extract not blurry images from video

Tags: panorama, video

I need a tool or code for extract not blurry images from video (it can be used for panorama or SFM building from video)

something like
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/groups/ivm/sharppanoramas/
(It is worth noting that [software](http://hdview.wordpress.com/2011/04/05/microsoft-ice-updatevideo-to-panorama-lens-vignette-improved-blending/) for building panorama from video is already exist, but I don't know why they don't use it for SFM)

I want to get images from video and put them to [vsfm](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~ccwu/vsfm/)

For example virtualdub gives blurry images when I try to convert video to images.

Comment: What if different parts of the image are in focus and others are not?  http://digital-photography-school.com/an-introduction-to-focus-stacking

Comment: I think extended focus is not related here and out of focus is not the same as motion blur. So we assume that focus length of camera don't change.

Answer (score 3):

One straightforward approach is to do blur detection (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180327/detection-of-blur-in-images-video-sequences) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765810/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-an-image-is-blurry)) and prune the frames that are detected.